# Connecting SonarLint into SonarQubeServer but issues not mapping

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarlint-intellij

I'm using sonarlint 4.12.1.22375 plugin in intelij, i have connected to sonarqube server Community EditionVersion 8.5 (build 37579) to use server's rules, but issues don't mapping beetween sonarlint and sonarqube server.

This is my issues in sonarqube server with 851 issues

[image]

But in sonarlint in intelij,I could only find 773 issues. File number scan is the same.
So why ?
I want to synchronized the issues among sonarqube server and sonarlint

Comment: Add a list of the analyzers (plugins) installed on the server, please.

Comment: i use sonar way (quality profile) in sonarqube server , it active 418 rules. 
Do you have it instructions ?

Comment: might be rleated to the fact, that sonarlint only works with sonarqubes own plugins, and not 3rd party plugins, like PMD, groovy etc.

Answer (score 2):

i recommend to check the installed plugins, either [API](https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/web_api/api/plugins/installed) or Web UI (Administration Rights needed). See if you have any 3rd party plugins (not official SonarQube Plugins) installed, it seems like that.

SonarLint does not support those 3rd Party Plugins, and will not show you any information regarding that. Regular used 3rd Party Plugins are Checkstyle, PMD, FindBugs/SpotBugs. See https://community.sonarsource.com/t/modify-sonarlint-to-run-third-party-analyzers/26808/2